# Is there a way to generate frames of a Matplotlib animation in response to an event?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a utility in Python that takes in information over a serial port, and graphs it. If I want live graphing, Matplotlib animations seem like the way to go. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do graphing on a basis that does not have a constant time interval. I define a FuncAnimation and one of the parameters is milliseconds. Instead, I'd like to have the graph update with a new data point whenever one is received over the serial port. How would I go about that, generating a frame event only on an as-needed basis? I've researched it a bit and found that Animations have a `event_source` parameter, but I don't know how to hook into that and how to actually fire an event that will generate a new frame. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Ideally I'd like to run something like animation.next_frame(), but that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819950/8881141)?

Comment: @Mr. T That method runs much, much slower than the normal time-based animation method. I think this is because it doesn't support blitting. But it seems close, since it does only animate when the event happens. If I could get the speed of an animation, with the time-flexibility of the method you linked, we'd be in business.